# what is alternative function if FIND_IN_SET is not support?

Tags: php, mysql

what is alternative function if `FIND_IN_SET` is not support in mysql(5.0.96). For some reason i cannot upgrade my mysql version.

**Table**

```
manufacturer_id | category_id
    15               63
    16               63,64
    17               163,64
```

**Query**

```
$category = '63';    

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `oc_manufacturer` WHERE find_in_set ('" . (int)$category ."', category_id)  ");
```

Result will return :

```
15
16
```

This query is working but how to get the same result without using `find_in_set` ?

Comment: The best approach (even if `find_in_set` was available) is always to properly design the database. The first step is always to remove multivalued fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `oc_manufacturer` WHERE 
CONCAT(',', category_id, ',') LIKE '%,".(int)$category.",%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using IN.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `oc_manufacturer` 
where ('" . (int)$category ."') in (category_id)  ");
```